# pivot_table function counting incorrect values from excel after reading it

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have spent quite sometime on this now. The count of values in column 'Lead Type' displayed by using pivot_tables is incorrect when I count the same values by using filter in the excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import warnings
import numpy as np

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True):
    warnings.simplefilter("always")
datam = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Complinity\Desktop\Marketing\CRM\Reports\CRM-Data 1 -31 July 2022.xlsx",engine="openpyxl", skiprows=[0,1])
datam = pd.DataFrame(datam, columns= ['Source','Medium','Keywords','Lead Type'])
datam_pivot_table = datam.pivot_table(index="Source",columns = "Lead Type", aggfunc="count", values="Medium",margins = True)
datam_pivot_table
```

Also when I used groupby function on the same dataframe to achieve the same result, my answers are in accordance with excel values.

```
new = datam.groupby(['Source', 'Lead Type']).agg({'Lead Type': ['count']}).reset_index()
new.columns = ['Source', 'Lead Type', 'Lead Count']
print (new)
new['Lead Count'].sum()
```

So why is pivot_table not working? Is it a cache issue or something else?

Comment: Probably not the solution to your problem, but pd.read_excel already returns a DataFrame so you you can delete the line datam = pd.DataFrame...

Comment: You probably have missing values - NaN values